# How to set breakpoints in V8 for GDB debugging?

Tags: security, reverse-engineering, v8

Hi I am new to GDB and V8. I'm wanting to set a breakpoint on a specific line within V8, for example any line in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/src/compiler/simplified-lowering.cc

How can I achieve this? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like setting a breakpoint in any other program, e.g:

```
(gdb) break simplified-lowering.cc:1234
```

See https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/ for details.

Comment: Hi, thank you I tried this. I'm using `./d8`, which is compiled from the V8 source. When I `gdb ./d8` and proceed to do `break simplified-lowering.cc:100`. I get the following `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`. When I use the file command against `d8` I get `No debugging symbols found in d8`.

Comment: @SarahM. Use a Debug build, or add `symbol_level = 2` to the build args of a Release build. (Debugging Release builds is going to be wonky though, that's what Debug builds are for.)